# How to apply list-disc to ul rendered by Markdownit?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, nuxtjs

I'm currently using Nuxtjs with Tailwind and @nuxtjs/markdownit.

I'm injecting the Markdown like this:

```html
<div v-html="$md.render(myMarkdownString)" class="styled"></div>
```

I have a list in said `myMarkdownString`, and have already applied some styles that work fine. Like this:

```css
.styled >>> strong,
.style >>> a {
  @apply text-black font-bold;
}

.style >>> ul {
  @apply bg-gray-200;
}
```

But when I use `@apply list-disc`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you: `list-disc` appeared to do nothing to the markup.

What appeared to fix this was adding a [list-inside](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-position) rule:

```css
ul {
  @apply list-inside list-disc;
}
```